# Android Sliding Drawer not Working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Implented Drawer with a SLider listner
But it does not work when swapping fingers Please Tell Me What i am doing wrong:
here is my frag class

```
public class frag extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.lists , container);
        return view;
    }

    public void setUp(int Fid ,DrawerLayout drawerLayout)
    {
            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer);
            drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            final ActionBar  ab = getActivity().getActionBar();
            ActionBarDrawerToggle abdl = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    getActivity(),
                    drawerLayout,
                    R.string.action_settings ,
                    R.string.hello_world)        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                    ab.setTitle("closed");
                }
           public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                ab.setTitle("opened");
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(abdl);
    }

    public void close()
    {
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
    }
}
```

here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:id="@+id/dll"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sidebarlist"
    android:text="thadssasdisk"
        android:textAlignment="center">
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Slider is not working, I want to create a side Navigation Drawer class
The Activity:

```
package com.example.shubham.navigation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DrawerLayout dl;
    frag fg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fg = (frag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sidebar);
        fg.setUp(R.id.drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer));
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.sidebarlist);
        drawer aa = new drawer(this);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
        aa.add("text");
        aa.add("fun");
        aa.add("learn");
        aa.add("To do");
        aa.add("Pending");
        aa.add("Current");
        aa.add("future");
        aa.add("Learn");
        aa.add("tasks");
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
               getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
             int id = item.getItemId();
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fg.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        fg.abdl.syncState();
    }
}
```

the alyout file wher fragment is called:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tview"
    android:text="hello world you know who"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/sidebar"
            class="com.example.shubham.navigation.frag"
            ></fragment>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: call `setUp` in `onCreateView`

Comment: any one else still not working

Comment: You haven't really included enough information to solve the problem; we need to see the activity hosting the fragment, when and how setup is called etc.

Comment: i have given every files and every thing

Comment: are there any errors you see? what have you already tried? what did you see with every attempt you made to fix this by yourself. That is what we need. Not a dump of your files with a statement sayings "its not working"

Comment: no errors the problem it is not working

Comment: yes i have read many tutorials changed the gravity layout

Comment: if there was a error i will be very happy but no error

Comment: @user49557 Ok, if there is no error from logcat, put some log on every important part of your code and report it to your answer. Maybe with some breakpoint with debug mode will help you.

Comment: well after a lot of debugging i found out that onDrawClosed function is n ot called even after progrmatically calling drawer to close i think there is some problem with linking what can on Drawer Closed not emitting show  or mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation for NavigationDrawer is completely wrong. You should call `setup()` from your parent activity's `onCreate()` function to initialize ActionBar and NavigationDrawer.
Sample code is given below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    ...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            }
        };

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Android docs: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Well this did not work for me but still i lhave left that problem behind for times so i will try it later but still i am going you the bounty

Answer (score 0):

When I implemented this, I used the following code with the help of this tutorial:

[sliding menu tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

**Drawer Adapter**

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

You then need to add the code for each fragment and the required resources respectively.

The xml layout file for the navigation slider would be similar to the one below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```